# Laravel 4 -> Routes on the same controller with multiple variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i've got some routes problems with Laravel. I think it's because i don't take the good method but...

Here is my code:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'products'), function()
{
    Route::get('', array('uses'=>'products@index'));
    //show all the products 

    Route::get('{Categorie}',array('uses'=>'products@categorie'))->where('Categorie','^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$');
    //show the products of this categorie   

    Route::get('{shopname}',array('uses'=>'products@shopname'))->where('shopname','^[a- z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$');
     //show the product of this shopname
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => '/products/{:any}'), function()
{
   //no index because productName is not optionnal

    Route::get('{productName}', array('uses'=>'product@getProduct'));
    //the Product controller is now SINGULAR
    //show this product in particular
});
```

So it's working for the first group...
   mysite.fr/products => ok
   mysite.fr/MyCategorie => ok
   mysite.fr/mashopname => ok

but when i add the second paramater like :

mysite.fr/products/myshopname/myfirstproduct

i got an error witouht specific message...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is these are all the same routes.  Laravel doesn't know what would count as a categorie, shopname, or any.  For example if I go to `/products/test`, Laravel won't know if test is a categorie, a shopname, or a name of a product.

Try this instead...

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'products'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'products@index'));
    //show all the products 

    Route::get('categorie/{Categorie}',array('uses'=>'products@categorie'))->where('Categorie','^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$');
    //show the products of this categorie   

    Route::get('shopname/{shopname}',array('uses'=>'products@shopname'))->where('shopname','^[a- z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$');
    //show the product of this shopname

    Route::get('product/{productName}', array('uses'=>'product@getProduct'));
    //the Product controller is now SINGULAR
});
```

This way, if I go to `products/categorie/test`, Laravel will know that I'm looking for a `categorie` and be able to route me appropriately.

Update:

If `Hightech` is a category and `product_1` is a product, you could use a route like this...

```
    Route::get('category/{categorie}/product/{product}',array('uses'=>'products@categorie'))->where('categorie','^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$')->where('product','^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$');
    //show the products of this categorie
```

And then the URL would be `.com/products/category/Hightech/product/product_1`.  Or you can take the `/product` out and `/category` out and you could just go to `.com/products/Hightech/product_1`

Comment: I thought of that but my idea was to keep the shopname/categorie in the url. Like you go on .com/products/Hightech/ then you go on .com/products/Hightech/product_1   .I tried this-> "Route::get('/{:any}/{productName}', array('uses'=>'product@getProduct'));" but still an error...

Comment: I just updated the answer so you'd be able to use a URL like that.